# Does Keras build model with wrong amount of neurons?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

i'm new to Keras. I created my model to work with [Fashion MNIST](https://www.kaggle.com/zalando-research/fashionmnist)

Here is my model:

```
model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
keras.layers.Dense(1),
keras.layers.Dense(1),
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)])

model.compile(optimizer= 'sgd', 
          loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['acc'])
```

As I understand this code is supposed to build this model

Flattener 28x28 to 1x784

Dense 1 neuron in = 1x784 | out = 1x1

Dense 1 neuron in = 1x1 | out = 1x10

Dense 1 neuron in = 1x10 | out = 1x10 (10 classes)

Problem is that model gives me **50% accuracy** on 60k example.It can't be true can it? There is no way that these 1 neuron layers and 1 weigth give enought information to classify images that well.

Its either Keras just ignore my values and insert neurons at its will or I don't understand how model is built.

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you considered that your assumption that this can't be true is well... completely incorrect? You run an experiment, and got 50% accuracy, there is no theory telling you what accuracy should get, so there is no expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the first layer has 784 weights, second has 1 the third has 10. Thats a total of 795 weights.

Although its not a great network design as you lose a lot of information on the second layer, the single weight can contain quite an amount of data.

Think of it this way, what if you build a network that has 2 layers: input and output. The value of the output if between 0-0.1 you give it a label class 1 0.1-0.2 -> class 2 and so on. You should be able to get a similar result to your network.

btw 50% correct classification is really bad for mnist. I usually get about 99%

Comment: But we have only 1 layer to process information from this 1 neuron and if this neuron gives positive number then, no mater what value is, in the next layer neuron that has the strongest weight will "fire" and if it gives negative value than neuron with the lowest weight will "fire" and if 0 than neuron with biggest bias will "fire". So it should recognize only 3 out of 10 classes but it get 5/10 classes right.

Comment: its not exactly that simple. with 784 inputs you have much more degrees of freedom and its hard to forecast what will happen. 

calling it firing is quite misleading because every neurons contribute to the output. if the weight is small, it contributes little and vise versa

The bottom line is that it gives a better prediction than a random prediction which will be correct 50% of the time